# Trying to display notifIt before reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hwy guys, I'm trying to show a notification before reloading the page. I have given the notification statement first and then the reloading statement. So, according to this logic, the notification should appear first and then the page should get reloaded. But, what happens is the page is getting reloaded, but notification is not appearing on the screen. If I remove the reloading statement, I get the notification. Why is that so? What should I do for getting the notification and then reload the page? This is what I've done:

```
success: function(data, text){
                        jQuery().msgbox_success(data.message);
                        window.location.replace("projection.php");  
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is asynchronous. The script will not stop after firing `msgbox_success()` and will go directly to `window.location.replace()`. The message has no time to be shown. There are a couple different ways to handle this:

1. Use an `alert()` instead. This force-pauses JavaScript execution. `alert(data.message)`
2. Wrap `window.location.replace()` in a `setTimeout` so that its execution is put off til a later time: `setTimeout(function(){ window.location.replace("projection.php"); }, 3000);`

Personally, I'd opt for #2.

Comment: This works. I want to bring the data which I saved in the database along with the success message here and just bind it with the same text box. Ho can I do that?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but I'm guessing something like this: `jQuery("input").val(someData + " " + data.message);` or `jQuery("div").text(someData + " " + data.message);`

Comment: What I meant was, I'm saving a value in the database and returning a message through json encode stating that the record is saved successfully. My question is, while returning the message can I bring the saved data and bind it to the same text box from where the value is sent. Got it?

Comment: Still not sure what you mean by "bring the saved data and bind it to the same text box from where the value is sent." I suggest making this into a new, separate question so you can expand on it further.